# Why round() is known by mingw but not by visual studio compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Sample code which is valid and gets compiled by gcc but not by VS compiler:

```
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    float x = 1233.23;
    x = round (x * 10) / 10;
    return 0;
}
```

but for some reason, when I am compiling this in Visual Studio I get an error:

```
C3861: 'round': identifier not found
```

I do include even `cmath` as someone suggested here: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/270269/boss_loken.cpp147-error-c3861-round-identifier-not-found

Is this function in gcc only?

Comment: It would be quite useful if there was an explanation for downvotes

Comment: The reason could be that you're supposed to post a minimal test case with which the problem can be reproduces, not a link to a wall of code.

Comment: I am using SO for quite a bit of time and this is a first time I hear of that. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: BTW isn't that one line a minimal test case of its own? Just calling round(int) seems to trigger this error, I suppose that linked code is too long and provided code is too short, but at some points it's pretty enough to realize what I have problem with.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `cmath` is not guaranteed to bring `round` into the global namespace, so your code could fail, even with an up-to-date, standards compliant C or C++ implementation. To be sure, use `std::round` (or `#include <math.h>`.)

Note that your C++ compiler must support `C++11` for `std::round` (`<cmath>`). A C compiler should support `C99` for `round` (from `<math.h>`.) If your version of MSVC doesn't work after the fix I suggested, it could simply be that that particular version is pre-C++11, or is simply not standards compliant.

Comment: This doesn't work. Using math.h produces the same error, and using std::round may fix the microsoft compiler, but breaks MinGW: xx.c:6:9: error: ‘round’ is not a member of ‘std’

Comment: @Petr OK, I understand the problem. You need C++11 support for this to be guaranteed to work (or C99 support for a C compiler). See edit.

Comment: No combination of the stuff in your answer solved the issue - either I get `identifier not found` or `round not a member of std::`.

Comment: @TomášZato Then your implementation must be non-conforming, or conforming to an old standard.

Comment: @juanchopanza This question is about visual studio compiler. OP didn't mark this answer as accepted and he had the same problem as me. I don't give a single damn whether MSVC compiler is outdated or ignores the specs, this question is about problems with MSVC compiler and therefore any standards are irrelevant.

Comment: @TomášZato OP has a potential problem in their code, which I pointed out. They ask if the function is GCC only, and implicit in my answer is that it isn't only GCC because it is standard C and C++. I can be more explicit and answer "Why round() is known by mingw but not by visual studio compiler", but the answer won't help you either.

Comment: @juanchopanza If you're about to answer questions literally instead of helping people you're just wasting your time posting. Your answer might be correct, but is not useful at all. And this question is top result on the visual studio error. Most people are primarily interested in solving the problem, something you obviously don't care much about.

Comment: @TomášZato I answered the best I could with the information at my disposal. OP hasn't comeback with more information. If you don't like it, go look somewhere else.

Comment: The information in question is sufficient. The SSCE he provided doesn't compile under msvc and it should. *If you don't like it, go look somewhere else.* - is just general defense reaction whenever someone is criticized. I shouldn't even reply to it.

Comment: @TomášZato The original title was "C3861: 'round': identifier not found". The code could easily fail to compile on a conforming and up to date implementation and my solution would have fixed the problem in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

You also can use a boost library:

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp>

const double a = boost::math::round(3.45); // = 3.0
const int b = boost::math::iround(3.45); // = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 (C99) doesn't support round but ceil and floor functions, so you may want to add your own function like;

```
long long int round(float a)
{
    long long int result;
    if (a-floor(a)>=0.5) 
       result = floor(a)+1;
    else
       result = floor(a);
    return result;
};
```

The `std::round` nor `#include <math.h>` supported at the VS 2010 according to my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I would use floor twice to get the correct rounded value,

```
long long int round(float a)
{
    long long int result = (long long int)floor(a);
    return result + (long long int)floor((a-result)*2)
};
```